# How to write a binary struct using python that can be read in c?

Tags: python, c

say a struct like this:

```
typedef struct testVertex_s {
       char *vert_name; //for test only...
       float x;
       float y;
       float z;
}testvertex_t;
```

how to write that to a binary file use python ?  I want to read it using fread in c;

Comment: Does it really make sense to have a char* in a struct that is defined outside of your program? How could it point to anything useful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why must it be binary? Text is trivial, and much simpler to interact with.

If you really want binary, use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module. Make sure to define your endianness, and read each field *separately* in C, do *not* try to do a single `fread()` into a C structure.

You could do the packing like so:

```
import struct
out = open("myvertex.bin", "wb")
string = "hello"
fmt = "<%usfff" % (1 + len(string))
out.write(struct.pack(fmt, string, 3.14, 47.11, 17))
```

This writes the string as a plain 0-terminated string, followed immediately by the floats. The resulting data from the above is `"hello\x00\xc3\xf5H@\xa4p<B\x00\x00\x88A"` (represented as a Python string literal).

For this case, you're going to need to dynamically allocate the string of course, which should be obvious.

Comment: How to handle variable length string in binary file?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You can either write out the nul terminator after the string or write out a n-byte length before the string.

Comment: @simonc yes understood. thanks unwind and simonc! and +1 to you